# communication between Mbed board with bluetooth and my app

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, transfer, mbed

At the moment I am using arm mbed K64F board connected with HC-05 BLE to send and receive message with android app( like sending and receiving 'hello'through one android app phone to another which both connected with K64F board.

Is it possible? or which kind of BLE component, board I should change?

Answer (score 0):

The full list of mbed enabled boards that can use BLE is listed here : https://os.mbed.com/platforms/?connectivity=3

A personal favorite of mine is the HRM1017.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the K64F, get the NUCLEO-IDB05A1 shield to add BLE connectivity.

Note, you need to buy the IDB0**5**A1, not the 4A1.